# Delete Session in ajax_request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to remove session in ajax request when user click logout button. But I cannot remove session properly by ajax request. What is solution, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

Comment: You mean you want to logout the user?

Comment: @Mahdi_Younesi yes logout, via ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created controller with method `logout` and provide route into that controller?

If not, then at routes add:

```
Route::post('/logout', 'LogoutController@logout');
```

Then create controller like bellow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LogoutController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Log the user out of the application.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

And then try to call Ajax request, as @NikolaGavric said:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/logout',
    success: function() {
        //
    }
});
```

It should work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/logout',
    success: function() {
        //
    }
});
```

That should do the trick

Comment: I use this code in external javascript file, when user click logout button then this code run. This code not working